# Continuity to show that point lies inside a set

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have some continuous curve $\gamma \colon [0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}^{n} $
with $\gamma ( 0) \in D\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and
$\gamma ( t) \not \in \partial D$ for all $t \in [ 0, 1]$. I want to show that
$\gamma ( 1) \in D$.

**Proof attempt:**
Since $[0, 1]$ is connected and $\gamma $ is continuous we also require
$\gamma [ [ 0, 1]]$ to be connected. Now suppose that $\gamma ( 1)
\in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus ( D \cup \partial D)$. Then we could write
$\gamma[ [0, 1]]$ as the union of disjoint open sets (subsets of $D$ and
$\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus (D \cup \partial D) $ respectively), which is a contradiction.

Is my above idea correct (I still have to make the argument rigorous)? Moreover, are there shorter/more elementary ways to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $D\cup\partial D$ is the closure of $D$, which is a closed set. If $\gamma(1)\notin D\cup\partial D$, then , since $(D\cup\partial D)^\complement$ is an open set, we have$$\gamma^{-1}(\{\gamma(1)\})=\gamma^{-1}\left((D\cup\partial D)^\complement\right),$$which is an open set, since $\gamma$ is continuous. But $\gamma^{-1}(\{\gamma(1)\})=\{1\}$ , which is *not* an open set.